# Using @ngrx/router-store actions with ngrx 8 createReducer() and on() function

Tags: angular, ngrx-router-store, ngrx-store-8.0

I have a `ngrx v8` style reducer (using createReducer + on) that needs to react to route changes.

```
let myAcction = createAction('my action', prop<boolean>);

let reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(myAction, (state, prop) => ({...state, example=prop })),
  on(ROUTER_NAVIGATION, (state, routeParams) => ({...state, example2:{...routeParams}}))
)
```

This fails to compile because `ROUTER_NAVIGATION` is not action creator:

> Argument of type '"@ngrx/router-store/navigation"' is not assignable
>   to parameter of type 'ActionCreator>'.
>         Type '"@ngrx/router-store/navigation"' is not assignable to type 'FunctionWithParametersType'

It does not work with `RouterNavigationAction` either:

> Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'ActionCreator>'

How can I use ngrx/router-store actions in createReducer/on functions? I can't find action creators exported for given actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would file an issue against ngrx on their repository. In the meantime, you can hack around it by using the token in an object: `{ type: ROUTER_NAVIGATION }` since this is how it works under the hood. It's not ideal, but it works until they fix it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean there. Do you mean write my own ActionCreator using ROUTER_NAVIGATION as first argument of createAction? Or is there some other way to specify type literal to the reducer on function?

Comment: `{ type: ROUTER_NAVIGATION }` specifies the type literal. Under the hood, the action creators just create another function, and add `type` as a property (it's a very non-typescript-y thing to do, but alas...). The reducer expects an object with property "type" so using this object literal instead of the constant itself will satisfy the compiler (hopefully).

Comment: Oh, cool! Thanks! (might update the answer with it?). What I ended up doing though, also because it's older codebase and needed to put some adapter in place for new stuff, is catch the router action in root effect and dispatch my own action created with createAction. Effects still allow constants in ofType. But good to know how it works!